# Bash read file to an array based on two delimiters

Tags: arrays, file, bash, parsing, ifs

I have a file that I need to parse into an array but I really only want a brief portion of each line and for only the first 84 lines. 
Sometimes the line maybe:

```
>MT gi...
```

And I would just want the MT to be entered into the array. Other times it might be something like this:

```
>GL000207.1 dn...
```

and I would need the GL000207.1

I was thinking that you might be able to set two delimiters (one being the '>' and the other being the ' ' whitespace) but I am not sure how you would go about it.  I have read other peoples posts about the internal field separator but I am really not sure of how that would work. I would think perhaps something like this might work though?

```
desiredArray=$(echo file.whatever | tr ">" " ")
for x in $desiredArray
do
   echo > $x
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Uh. No. I actually just started with Bash like... a week ago. I am trying to learn it for my work. How do you use cut?

Comment: The shell is generally poor at text processing. You could get tricky with `IFS` but you'll do better to use `cut` as suggested or `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: Never mind, I had the mistaken idea in my head `cut` supported multiple delimiters. In short: no it doesn't, forget I said anything...

Comment: From what I read I would need to have the same number of characters in each setting to use cut. One of my problems though, is that I don't always require the same number of characters, so I couldn't just use an over reaching cut command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
head -84 <file> | awk '{print $1}' | tr -d '>'
```

`head` takes only the first lines of the file, `awk` strips off the first space and everything after it, and `tr` gets rid of the '>'.

Comment: So essentially what this line of code says is... From the beginning through line 84 of a particular file, take everything before the space and delete the >?

Comment: That's pretty much the idea, yes. Although if there are ever lines where you don't want the entire first field (minus the '>'), you'd need some additional rules, but both cases cited in the original question would be solved by this pattern.

Comment: I am not sure how this works as an array. How would you reference the values at a later point?

Comment: Based on what the question stated, I'm not sure you're looking for a bash array (which you could get with `arrayvar=($(head -84 ....) )`. The original syntax in your `for x in ...` is just dealing with a space-separated list in a single variable, for which the `desiredArray=$(...)` syntax should work fine. If you do the `arrayvar` bit, you can then reference `${arrayvar[14]}`, etc., instead of just `for x in ...`.

Comment: Nope. Just reads the file and prints out the altered/filtered contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with sed:

```
head -n 84 <file> | sed 's/>\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Except `tail -n 84 <file>` gives the *last* lines of the file, not the *first* ones.

Comment: o dear :) not sure why I entered tail... fixed now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: no worries... most of us use `tail` a lot more anyway, so it's a natural mistake...